# code doesn't seem to run after if statement inside function

Tags: python

I'm following some online courses and I have this function `sort` but nothing nothing seems to run after the `print "here"` part:

```
import unittest


def sort(meetings, indx):
    print("call function")
    print meetings
    firstfirst = meetings[indx][0]
    firstsecond = meetings[indx][1]
    secondfirst = meetings[indx+1][0]
    secondsecond = meetings[indx+1][1]

    first = meetings[indx]
    second = meetings[indx+1]

    print firstfirst
    print secondfirst

    if firstfirst > secondfirst:
        meetings[indx] = second
        meetings[indx+1] = first
    print "here"
    indx = index + 1
    print "meetings: "
    sort(meetings[indx:len(meetings)-1], indx)

def merge_ranges(meetings):

    # Merge meeting range

    sort(meetings, 0)

    return []


# Tests



class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_meetings_overlap(self):
        actual = merge_ranges([(1, 3), (2, 4)])
        expected = [(1, 4)]
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    def test_meetings_touch(self):
        actual = merge_ranges([(5, 6), (6, 8)])
        expected = [(5, 8)]
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    def test_meeting_contains_other_meeting(self):
        actual = merge_ranges([(1, 8), (2, 5)])
        expected = [(1, 8)]
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    def test_meetings_stay_separate(self):
        actual = merge_ranges([(1, 3), (4, 8)])
        expected = [(1, 3), (4, 8)]
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    def test_multiple_merged_meetings(self):
        actual = merge_ranges([(1, 4), (2, 5), (5, 8)])
        expected = [(1, 8)]
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    def test_meetings_not_sorted(self):
        actual = merge_ranges([(5, 8), (1, 4), (6, 8)])
        expected = [(1, 4), (5, 8)]
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    def test_sample_input(self):
        actual = merge_ranges([(0, 1), (3, 5), (4, 8), (10, 12), (9, 10)])
        expected = [(0, 1), (3, 8), (9, 12)]
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)


unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

the output shows this and only throws errors for the test cases (which I didn't include) since those are to be expected...

```
call function
[(1, 8), (2, 5)]
1
2
here
call function
[(5, 8), (1, 4), (6, 8)]
5
1
here
call function
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
1
2
here
call function
[(1, 3), (4, 8)]
1
4
here
call function
[(5, 6), (6, 8)]
5
6
here
call function
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (5, 8)]
1
2
here
call function
[(0, 1), (3, 5), (4, 8), (10, 12), (9, 10)]
0
3
here
```

Comment: `index` is a very strange variable, coming from nowhere. May be it should be `indx`...

Comment: Spent hours looking at this...thanks!

Comment: I misread a portion of your code and made some edits and suggestions accordingly

Comment: added a suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "but nothing nothing seems to run after the print "here" part"

Are you basing this on the fact that nothing else prints? If so thats because you have to print the variables you change. Also, none of your functions return anything you have worked on within the function and while sort mutates the meetings variable it has no way of knowing when to stop calling itself, it will just eventually throw an error when trying to index into an empty list held in the meetings variable. Even your use of print is confusing. You use `print("call function")` up top then `print meetings` afterwards mixing python 2 & 3 print syntax.

But let's get to the heart of your problem here.

```
def sort(meetings, indx):
    print("call function")
    print meetings
    # eventually meetings will be an empty list and meetings[indx] 
    # will throw an IndexError
    firstfirst = meetings[indx][0]
    firstsecond = meetings[indx][1]
    secondfirst = meetings[indx+1][0]
    secondsecond = meetings[indx+1][1]

    first = meetings[indx]
    second = meetings[indx+1]

    print firstfirst
    print secondfirst

    if firstfirst > secondfirst:
        meetings[indx] = second
        meetings[indx+1] = first
    # "here" is printed
    print "here"  
    # you alter the indx variable but do not print it
    indx = index + 1  
    # "meetings:" is printed but nothing else is printed below it
    print "meetings: "  
    # sort calls itself without any condition to stop calling itself 
    # and which will eventually have the indx variable exceed the 
    # meetings length in the call:
    #     meetings[indx:len(meetings)-1]
    sort(meetings[indx:len(meetings)-1], indx)  
    # nothing is returned here and sort does not mutate the object in 
    # any way that I could see that would cause sort to stop 
    # calling itself

def merge_ranges(meetings):

    # Merge meeting range

    sort(meetings, 0)

    return []  # <- this empty list is always returned no matter what
```

- sort doesn't return anything, which isn't a huge issue if you are just mutating something
- sort calls itself recursively until it exceeds the recursion limit, there is nothing to tell it to stop calling itself

Lets assume meetings is this list

```
meetings = [(0, 1), (3, 5)]
meetings[5:] # ==> [] will always return an empty list when indx exceed meetings length
```

This means sort keeps calling itself with an empty list and a higher index number

- merge_meetings always returns an empty list

You need to test for the index being larger than `len(meetings)`

Suggestion:
Assuming python 3

```
def sort(meetings, indx):
    print("call function")
    print(meetings)
    first = meetings[indx]
    second = meetings[indx+1]
    firstfirst = first[0]
    firstsecond = first[1]
    secondfirst = second[0]
    secondsecond = second[1]

    print(firstfirst)
    print(secondfirst)

    if firstfirst > secondfirst:
        meetings[indx] = second
        meetings[indx+1] = first
    indx = index + 1
    print("meetings: ", meetings)
    if len(meetings) - 1 > indx:
        sort(meetings[indx:], indx)
```

Now while this takes care of stopping the recursive calls it still doesn't sort completely, it sorts the 2 elements relative to their position to each other but it will need several passes to acheive a proper sort.
for example:

```
In [1]: a = [(5,3), (0,2), (4,1), (1,1)]
In [2]: sort(a, 0)
call function
[(0, 2), (5, 3), (4, 1), (1, 1)]
0
5
meetings:  [(0, 2), (5, 3), (4, 1), (1, 1)]
call function
[(5, 3), (4, 1), (1, 1)]
4
1
meetings:  [(5, 3), (1, 1), (4, 1)]

In [3]: a
Out[3]: [(0, 2), (5, 3), (4, 1), (1, 1)]
```

I'll leave that up to you to figure out seeing as this was an assignment.